# Autocomplete does not refresh its items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I am using autocomplete with angularjs.

Everytime I select a value from a dropdownlist the items that fill the autocomplete should change. But they does not change.
I see that the model change, but not the outcomplete.

Here the directive I am using for autocomplete.

```
.directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        iElement.autocomplete({
            source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
            select: function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    iElement.trigger('input');
                }, 0);
            }
        });
    };
})
```

And here how I use the autocomplete:

```
<input type="text" name="indirizzo" data-ng-model="input.indirizzo" auto-complete ui-items="indirizzi" data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'mousedown blur' }" />
```

Everytime I change the dropdownlist the `$scope.indirizzi` change correctly but not for the autocomplete.

Perhaps I should use a `watch` or something similar?
Any suggestions?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

Perhaps I have not explained good. 
I Have a dropdownlist that when a value is selected from, fill my autocomplete list (like some cascade dropdown).

Here the dropdownlist:

```
<select name="state" data-ng-options="s for s in states" data-ng-model="input.state" data-ng-change="fillAutoComplete(input.state)" />
```

The `fillAutocomplete` function is :

```
$scope.fillAutoComplete = function (state) {
        $scope.indirizzi = ...
}
```

Now, everything I change the value in the dropdown, the `$scope.indirizzi` is correctly updated, but the autocomplete list is not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my directive as following:

```
.directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
        return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });

            scope.$watch(iAttrs.uiItems, function () {
                iElement.autocomplete("option", "source", scope[iAttrs.uiItems]);
            });
        };
    })
```

See the scope.$watch

Answer (score 0):

**Please check this example auto-complete using angular.**

```
<div ng-app='MyModule'>
<div ng-controller='DefaultCtrl'>
    <input auto-complete ui-items="names" ng-model="selected">
    selected = {{selected}}
</div>
```

**JsCode**

```
  function DefaultCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];
}

angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    };
});
```

[JSFiddle Working](http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/light/)

Comment: Perhaps I have not been clear. I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete is a jQuery plugin, I guess you have to call $scope.$apply() to let Angular know that you have changed something.